# Cannot remove trailing space in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

This is in SQL Server 2005. I have a `varchar` column and some rows contain trailing space, e.g. `abc`, `def`.

I tried removing the trailing space with this command:

```
update thetable 
set thecolumn = rtrim(thecolumn)
```

But the trailing space remains. I tried to find them using:

```
select * 
from thetable 
where thecolumn <> rtrim(thecolumn)
```

But it returned nothing.

Are there some settings that I am not aware that influences trailing space check?

EDIT:

I know that there is trailing space from SSMS, when I copy paste the value from the grid to the editor, it has trailing space.

Comment: What is the datatype of `thecolumn`?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the trailing spaces (on a web page, in SSMS)?

Comment: The data type is varchar

Comment: @Joe from SSMS, I copy paste the value from the grid to the editor

Comment: Are you sure they are actually spaces, not tabs or something. If your column is `varchar` the first query should have worked (though the second query won't work as trailing spaces are ignored in such comparisons)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if the spaces that are not removed have the ASCII code 32.
Try this to replace "hard space" with "soft space":

```
update thetable set thecolumn = rtrim(replace(thecolumn, char(160), char(32)))
```

the query was missing equal sign

Comment: OMG it's a char(9)!! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Тhat's strange. This solve my issue too, so +1, but what's the real difference between "HARD" and "SOFT" spaces?

Answer (score 8):

Are you certain that it is a space (ascii 32) character? You can get odd behavior with other "non-visible" characters. Try running

```
select ascII(right(theColumn, 1))
 from theTable
```

and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it's char(9), not char(32). But Crassy answered earlier, so I give the answer to him. Upvoted!

Comment: FYI, char(9) is the Tab character.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Function:

Create Function [dbo].[FullTrim] (@strText varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max) as
Begin

```
Declare @Ch1 char,@ch2 char
Declare @i int,@LenStr int
Declare @Result varchar(max)
Set @i=1
Set @LenStr=len(@StrText)
Set @Result=''


While @i<=@LenStr
Begin
    Set @ch1=SUBSTRING(@StrText,@i,1)
    Set @ch2=SUBSTRING(@StrText,@i+1,1)
    if ((@ch1=' ' and @ch2=' ') or (len(@Result)=0 and @ch1=' '))

        Set @i+=1

    Else
        Begin
            Set @Result+=@Ch1
            Set @i+=1

        End

End
```

Return @Result
End

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL`, `CHAR(n)` columns are right-padded with spaces to their length.

Also string comparison operators (and most functions too) do not take the trailing spaces into account.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (c CHAR(10), vc VARCHAR(10))

INSERT
INTO    @t
VALUES  ('a   ', 'a    ')

SELECT  LEN(c), LEN(vc), с + vc
FROM    @t

--
1    1    "a         a"
```

Please run this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    thetable
WHERE   thecolumn + '|' <> RTRIM(thecolumn) + '|'
```

and see if it finds something.

Comment: In SQL Server `VARCHAR` are not right trimmed try `SELECT '[' + vc + ']' FROM    @t`. Think `ANSI_PADDING` might affect this though. (At least that's what it says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx but doesn't seem to make any difference this end!)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either:

1) Whatever you are using to view the values is inserting the trailing space (or the appearance thereof- try a fixed-width font like Consolas).

2) The column is CHAR, not VARCHAR.  In that case, the column will be padded with spaces up to the length of the column, e.g. inserting 'abc' into char(4) will always result in 'abc '

3) You are somehow not committing the updates, not updating the right column, or other form of user error.  The update statement itself looks correct on the face of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with RTRIM() AND LTRIM() functions.

In my situation the problem was in LF and CR chars.

Solution

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(100)
SET @test = 'Declaration status  '

SET @test = REPLACE(REPLACE(@test, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
```